How to remove padding between navigation bar title and first item of Form when using .inline display mode
I am trying to display a form as a sheet that contains some data entry items. I want to display the navigation title in .inline display mode. But there is a large gap between the navigation bar title and the first item in the Form. I'm trying to achieve something similar to Apple's Reminders app.
Apple Reminders app:

My app:

Here is the code for a simple separate project I made to try and achieve this:
@main
struct Test1App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isSheetShown = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Sheet") {
            isSheetShown = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetShown) {
            SheetView()
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @State private var title = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Title", text: $title)
            }
            .navigationTitle("New Reminder")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {}
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                    Button("Save") {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I am on Xcode 15.4 (15F31d) and iOS 17.5
What I tried

Adding section with empty title

Form {
    Section(header: Text("")) {
        TextField("Title", text: $title)
    }
}

Result: Did not work, this actually increased the padding a small amount

Setting .listSectionSpacing

Form {
    Section(header: Text("")) {
        TextField("Title", text: $title)
    }
}
.listSectionSpacing(80)

Result: Did not work, seems like this only affects spacing between two sections
Any help here would be appreciated.

Some workarounds/hacks for reducing the gap can be found as answers to How to remove top space of Form in SwiftUI?. In particular, adding negative padding to the Form seems to work: .padding(.top, -30)

Instead of adding a .toolbar and a .navigationTitle, you can just show a custom header. This might mean, you don't even need to surround the Form with a NavigationStack. A NavigationStack is only needed if nested navigation is happening inside the sheet.
If you try to use a VStack as the layout container for the custom header and the form, the form still has a large-ish space above it. So an alternative approach is to show the header as an overlay in the space above the form. Doing it this way, you'll actually need to add some padding to make more space for the header:
// SheetView

var body: some View {
    Form {
        TextField("Title", text: $title)
    }
    .padding(.top, 20)
    .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
    .overlay(alignment: .top) {
        Text("New Reminder")
            .font(.headline)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .overlay(alignment: .leadingFirstTextBaseline) {
                Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {}
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .trailingFirstTextBaseline) {
                Button("Save") {}
                    .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
            }
            .padding(.top)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
}



I see, but this doesn't achieve the same behavior as surrounding the Form with NavigationStack when you scroll the form up, where the navigation bar background color changes to white and shows a divider, which is what I wanted. And the Apple Reminders app achieves this while also having navigation within the sheet, so I thought it should be possible without using a custom header... see screenshots https://imgur.com/a/Be5gxDB

@user26789740 If the Material background is your only concern then this could be applied to the custom header when the form is scrolled. A GeometryReader can be used to detect when scrolling has happened. However, if you are planning on nested navigation inside the sheet then I expect the navigation title and toolbar may also need to change when a nested context is navigated to. This begins to get more complicated, you might be better off trying some of the workarounds/hacks suggested in How to remove top space of Form in SwiftUI? instead.
